# Update some table when changes are made in a specific table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

This is the database diagram of my sample database:

[image]

I want to UPDATE ***Ingredient*** Table when changes are made into ***OrderDetails*** table with the help of ***Table Trigger***

But the problem is that the ***Ingredients*** table may have one or more entries for an Item. I want to update all entries in ***Ingredient*** table which are associated with an Item. For more description, see the algorithm below:

For each ***Ingredient*** in ***Ingredients*** for the current *Item*:
Update the ***Quantity*** in ***Ingredient*** table using the formula:
formula: Ingredient.Quantity = Ingredient.Quantity - (Item.Quantity * Ingredients.Quantity)

**(The whole idea is whenever Item(s) for an OrderID is Added/Updated/Deleted, the Ingredient(s) Quantity should be decreased/increased by the Quantity mentioned)**

Comment: search for triggers or do multiple queries on same event

Comment: @polin I have already searched for triggers. But the problem is **how do I iterate for all the ingredients for the current item?**

Comment: there are many ways. But my suggestion would be write a procedure where you insert into many tables when the procedure is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't iterate or loop in SQL (unless we can avoid it). We describe *what* we want to happen, and let SQL work out *how*.

We also, generally, don't *store* data that we can compute. We can always compute the amount of each ingredient that has been ordered. (If there's another table tracking deliveries from our suppliers, that could also be computed over). If performance was an issue, we'd then consider creating an indexed view - which does include the calculated values, but SQL Server takes care of maintaining it automatically.

In that way, you avoid any discrepancies from creeping in (e.g. if your trigger is disabled).

All that being said, I think the trigger you want is:

```
create trigger T_OrderDetails
on OrderDetails
after insert,update,delete
as
begin
    update ing
    set Quantity = ing.Quantity - ((COALESCE(iod.Quantity,0) - COALESCE(dod.Quantity,0)) * i.Quantity)
    from
    inserted iod
        full outer join
    deleted dod
        on
            iod.ItemID = dod.ItemID
        inner join
    Ingredients i
        on
            i.ItemID = iod.ItemID or
            i.ItemID = dod.ItemID --Cope with OUTER join above
        inner join
    Ingredient ing
        on
            i.IngID = ing.IngID
end
```